# Theorem 5.7.1 Hartshorne, (Duality for $\mathbb{P}_k^n$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = \mathbb{P}_n^k$ over a field $k$. Let $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}(q)$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why is it that $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, \omega)\cong H^0(X, \omega(-q))$?

I like to interpret $H^0(X, \omega(-q))$ as global meromorphic sections of the canonical sheaf with poles of degree $q$. Then I can interpret $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, \omega)$ as group of $\mathcal{O}_X$ module homomorphism between the structure sheaf but allowing sections having zeros of degree $q$ to the canonical sheaf (i.e structure sheaf but allowing poles of degree $n+1$.)

However, I don't see how these two are isomorphic,

Comment: I know you want to interpret it in terms of forms, but that is a red herring. For any scheme $X$ and two line bundles $L,M$ on $X$, you have $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M)=H^0(X, L^{-1}\otimes M)$.

Comment: Thank you for letting you know. Where are you getting the equality from?

Comment: This is standard. Given $f:L\to M$, we get a map (which I call by $f$ still), $f:L^{-1}\otimes L=\mathcal{O}_X\to L^{-1}\otimes M$. This is just a section of $L^{-1}\otimes M$. So we get map $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M)\to H^0(L^{-1}\otimes M)$. You can either define an inverse map or check this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Not hard at all. I just had not thought of it!